# Getting Null values for the Long length Strings

Tags: php, string, null, decode

```
$val="";
$val = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes(trim($_POST['feed'])));
$name = stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['name']));
if (isset($val)) {
      error_log("*********************************");
      $json = array();
      $temp = json_encode($val);
      error_log("ENCODED VALUE = ". $temp);
      $decoded = json_decode($temp);
```

Whenever, I provide long length string to the 'val', the decoded value gets null. However, it provides correct value in case of the short length string. 
Need help.

Comment: what is the $_POST['feed'] value you 've tried?

Comment: Use `php_value post_max_size 16M` in .htaccess. This will solve your problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use any `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: I too faced the similar problem. and $_POST['feed'] contains a multiline String of around 1500 characters.